# Calculating additional props in styled component

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I have a fairly simple styled component but I want to use the props to calculate some additional props for use in interpolations later. I realise that I could do the calculations inside the expressions but that would mean repeating them multiple times. Here is my code.

```
const StyledColumns = styled.div.attrs({
    columnWidths: props => calculateColumnWidths(props)
})`

    display: grid;
    grid-column-gap: 40px;
    grid-row-gap: 20px;

    grid-template-columns: ${props => props.columnWidths[0]}

    // Use props.columnWidths a few more times...

`
```

There are two problems here - (A) I get an error saying that upper-case characters can't be used in attribute names and (B) That's made me realise that the attributes are actually added in the DOM to the div. I thought this was just a handy way to calculate additional props.

Is there a better way of doing this so I only have to run the calculations once but  nothing appears in the rendered DOM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest wrapping your styled-component in a HOC to make the calculation there.

```
const StylisedColumn = React.memo(props => {
  const columnWidths = calculateColumnWidths(props);
  const Column = styled.div`
    display: grid;
    grid-column-gap: 40px;
    grid-row-gap: 20px;
    grid-template-columns: ${columnWidths[0]}

    // Use columnWidths a few more times...
  `;

  return <Column {...props} />;
});
```

use React.memo to avoid re-renders, like pure components :)